# What if I don't declare a reused volume in the top level `volumes` key of a compose file

Tags: docker, permissions, mount, docker-compose, docker-swarm

[The compose specification says:](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes)

> To reuse a volume across multiple services, a named volume MUST be declared in the top-level `volumes` key.

I am currently trying to debug an application with a docker bind mount issue. I noticed that the compose.yaml file for this application declares the volume `${EXTRA_VOLUME}` under every service.

Every other reused volume is (1) declared under the services that use it and (2) declared under the top level `volumes` key. Therefore, the other volumes are compliant with the specification.

The `${EXTRA_VOLUME}` is (1) declared under the services that use it, but NOT declared under the top level `volumes` key.

**So, I am wondering:** What happens to `${EXTRA_VOLUME}`? What problems should I expect?

Comment: Either `EXTRA_VOLUME` will resolve to a filesystem path, in which case you get a bind mount, or it will look like a volume name and fail with an error like "ERROR: Named volume "foo:/foo:rw" is used in service "my_service" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.".

Answer (score 0):

Docker has [a page dedicated to this](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/), where they go over the differences between volumes, bind-mounting implicitly (with `--volume`) and bind-mounting explicitly (with `--mount`).

To summarise, and to put in the context of `docker compose`, the `volumes:` top-level section is for declaring volumes that have to go through a volume driver (e.g. local filesystem-backed volumes under `/var/lib/docker/volumes`, NFS mounts, SMB mounts, EBS block volumes, etc). Docker controls the volume's lifecycle, when it gets created, mounted, deleted, etc.

Bind-mounting a filesystem path provides similar functionality, but it's unmanaged by docker: it's simply a filesystem path/file being made accessible at a given (inside) path when starting the container. Because it's so much simpler, and there's no volume driver involved, it doesn't need (indeed, it shouldn't!) be declared as a `volume:` entry.